# Use nested circles as legend

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to use nested circles as legend in Python in a seaborn scatterplot where I used their size to indicate a quantity.

For now I managed, using the legend's labels and handles, to get two circles for the two extremes. Would you know how I can nest them?

I have in mind something like this: 
[image: (ggplot)]

Comment: Huhh that is hard. (I would estimate 4 hours of work. But if someone is willing to do that, it would be a great addition to the matplotlib gallery!)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to draw stacked circles in legend by writing Handlers. Here is the implementation.
This will give the figure like [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HttRR.png) and would be modified to what you need.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.collections import PathCollection
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerLine2D, HandlerPathCollection

class HandlerPath(HandlerPathCollection):
    """
    Custom Handler for HandlerPathCollection instances.
    """
    def create_artists(self, legend, orig_handle,
                       xdescent, ydescent, width, height, fontsize, trans):
        xdata, xdata_marker = self.get_xdata(legend, xdescent, ydescent,
                                             width, height, fontsize)
        leglines = []
        legline_1 = Line2D([10], [5], marker='o', markerfacecolor='darkred', markersize=10, alpha=0.3)
        legline_2 = Line2D([10], [5], marker='o', markerfacecolor='darkred', markersize=20, alpha=0.3)
        legline_1.set_color("darkred")
        legline_2.set_color("darkred")
        leglines.append(legline_1)
        leglines.append(legline_2)
        return leglines

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

l = ax.plot([0.5, 0, -0.5], [0.5, 0, -0.5], linestyle = '--', color='darkred', marker='o', label="TinyTL")
c = ax.scatter([0.5, 0, -0.5], [0.5, 0, -0.5] , s = 1e3, alpha=0.3, color="darkred")
ax.legend(
    l+[c], ["line", "circles"],
    handler_map={
        Line2D: HandlerLine2D(),
        PathCollection: HandlerPath()
    },
    handlelength=2.5, handleheight=3
)

plt.savefig('test.png')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I want to achieve the same legend of the nested circles. The following is my implementation:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.legend_handler as mhandler
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = [[ 0,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0],
       [ 2,  0,  6,  0,  0,  6,  0,  0],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  2,  3,  0,  0,  2],
       [ 8,  0,  8,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 6,  6,  6,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [10,  6,  2,  0,  0,  2,  0,  0],
       [10, 10,  2,  0,  4,  2,  0,  0],
       [ 8,  9,  8, 20, 10,  0,  8,  2]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data).reset_index().melt(id_vars=['index'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7), dpi=100)

bubbles = ax.scatter(
    df['index'], df['variable'], 
    s=df['value']*70, # So that the marker is larger
    marker='o', 
    c='#FFB24D', edgecolor='#FF6A1C', lw=1.5,
    )

# Set markers' properties before they are used as the legend handles.
def set_marker_color(handle, orig_handle):
    handle.update_from(orig_handle)
    handle.set_facecolor('w')
    handle.set_edgecolor('k')
    
legend = ax.legend([bubbles], ['value'], handletextpad=2,
                   scatterpoints=3, # Choose three marker points for a legend entry
                   handler_map={
                       type(bubbles):
                           mhandler.HandlerPathCollection(
                               sizes=[30*70, 10*70, 2*70], # Choose the corresponding size.
                               marker_pad=1,  # So that all points have the same x coordinate.
                               yoffsets=[0, -1.2, -2.1],  # Offset in the y direction to get the expected layout.
                               update_func=set_marker_color)},  # If not, the legend handles will be same as the original handles.
                   frameon=False,
                   loc='lower left', 
                   bbox_to_anchor=(0.01, 1.05))
```

[image]

After that, you can use `ax.text` or `ax.annotate` to add some labels in the legend handles.

However, I haven't figured out any way to add the number labels automatically, or to get the `marker_pad` and `yoffsets` automatically.

I hope this can be a start, and someone can find a more generic way to achieve this kind of legend.